# How to fix unable to resolve module react redux hooks\useDispatch?

Tags: reactjs, native

I was trying to use react-redux for my react native app but somehow this problem came up

```
error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `./hooks/useDispatch` from `C:\Users\TF\lesson\node_modules\react-redux\lib\index.js`: The module `./hooks/useDispatch` could not be found from `C:\Users\TF\lesson\node_modules\react-redux\lib\index.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:;
```

I have tried reinstalling and rerunning the react-redux@6 but i cant seem to understand why it needs a hook\useDispatch.

How may i go about to get my installation done properly?

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: same error in react-redux@6.0.0 :(

Answer (score 6):

This solution solved my problem, open terminal and run

`react-native start --reset-cache` and leave it open and run this
`react-native run-android` in another terminal

Answer (score 2):

If you use expo, then run the following command to reset the expo cache:

expo r -c

This is where I found the information:
https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues/1247

Answer (score 1):

Try to install the latest version of react-redux "npm i react-redux@latest"